# "Quotation" tag is being ignored

Tags: mpdf

I am using the "q" (quotation) HTML tag, supported by mPDF (https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-tags.html). It's visible in HTML output in any web browser but mPDF seems to be ignoring it. Did someone try to use "q" tag?

I thing issue is related to pseudo-elements ":after" and ":before", not supported by mPDF. When I inspect thru Firefox code, I can see browser shows this code:

```
<q lang="ES-es">
  ::before
  My quoted text</q>
  ::after
</q>
```

And this is the real code:

```html
<q lang="ES-es">My quoted text</q>
```

However, quotes are not showed in PDF output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ::before and ::after pseudo-elements are [not supported in mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/770).

Comment: So "<q>" tag should be removed from "supported" tags cause is based in those pseudo-elements and doesn't work.

Comment: No, CSS pseudo-elements have no direct relation to specific HTML elements and q tag [has meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) even when used with no CSS whatsoever. The reason your browser shows you the elements in the preview is that they are defined in the linked CSS.

Comment: But, then why is not working? Am I only one using "q" tag in mPDF?

Comment: It is not working because CSS pseudo-elements are not supported in mPDF.

Comment: Meaning, mPDF still recognizes `q` tag, but that does not mean it will render contents of its ::before and ::after pseudo-elements.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but, is it not supposed that if a tag is "supported" it will be rendered by mPDF like in a web browser HTML page. If it doesn't work that way, simply is not supported!!! ;)

Comment: By this logic, no tag is supported because its ::before and ::after pseudo-elements will not be rendered like in a web browser. So yes, you're wrong ;)

Comment: Supported means: It works. And "q" doesn't work in mPDF, so must not appear as "Supported". Independently if indeed it uses or not (as I gathered) internally pseudo-elements. User is NOT using those pseudo-elements. Maybe could be part of the way "q" works but user is not using pseudo-elements in "q" tag (that really can be used). So NO Finwe, I'm not wrong when I insist telling "q" should not appear as supported.